# Can I send font files with a "Free for Personal and Commercial Use" license to a client?

Tags: fonts, font-licensing

I have done a Typographic T-shirt design and I’m handing files to the client very soon. The client is going to use my design to print on shirts and sell them.

I used fonts with a "Free for Personal and Commercial Use" license. I checked all the font's licenses from the website where I downloaded each font.

Can I send the files to the client or do I need to do more license checks of the fonts used before handing over the files? If yes, what type of checks?

Designs submitted to the client for the final review and choice.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you even need to send the font files? You more than likely just need to outline the type.

Comment: If the font is free, you could just tell them what it is, and where they can download it, without having to redistribute any files at all.

Comment: I don't know yet if the client will ask me to send them the fonts. I personally prefer not to send any fonts, instead i would to outline the text, expand and flatten the images, then send the design. I checked the fonts and the License says "Free for Personal and Commercial Use". If they have an in house designer or somebody that is able/willing to download the fonts they could do that.

Comment: If i outline the text does that means that i'm not redistributing any font right?

Comment: Yes, if you outline the type then they'll just be regular vector shapes like any other paths you have in your design—so no sending font files. For something like this you should probably be doing that anyway; regardless of any licensing issues.

Comment: If you've found either of the below answers to answer your question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your font has a "Free for Personal and Commercial Use" license then you should pretty much be fine. It's impossible to say without seeing each license but just double check for anything regarding "redistribution" or similar. Since the fonts are free to use you could, if there are any issues, simply supply a link to where the free font is available for download...

All of that being said; you can (and in cases like this—where the type is more akin to artwork than copy—should) outline your type (e.g. in Adobe Illustrator you select the type and go to *Type → Create Outlines*). This converts your type to vector shapes, so all you'll be sending to your client or printer or whoever is vector artwork and not any font files.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check if the font you are using is copyrighted or unusable for commercial use, if not then go ahead and use the font but you should also take into context that the font my have a commercial usage fee which could cause you to get a fine.

Also dependant on how famous/popular the text font is could depend upon costs and copyright issues, the owner may have inputted a cost-of-use after you downloaded it.

It would really help if you could either send a picture of the design or the font name so I can look into this subject more but overall the font seems usable but make sure you double check before going ahead and using the font

Comment: do you have a licence if so what type

Comment: The question explicitly says *I used fonts with a "Free for Personal and Commercial Use" license*

Comment: Thanks RaGe MaGiXZ, I double checked the License of the fonts and all of them are Free for Commercial use. Previously i wanted to use 2 fonts that i particularly liked but they are free for personal use only so i had to look for other fonts.   AT the moment the clients is reviewing 8 different designs and he will choose 1 design. Sure will update the designs in a minute so you can look at them. I appreciate your help and thank you in advance.